# How to find velocity vector at a point of intersection of two planes?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

A particle moves at constant speed 1630 units along the curve of intersection of the two surfaces y=x^2 and z= (2/3)x^3  in the direction of increasing x.
Find it's velocity when it is at the point (-9, 81, -486).

I know how to find velocity vectors at a point, however I'm very confused by it being the intersection of two surfaces.  How would I approach this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think moving 1630 units is enough to tell us anything about speed.

Comment: yes I was also confused by that, but that's all the question states..

Comment: I agree with Ahmed. You need to know something about the time to say anything about the velocity.

Comment: @ Megannn: The curve is formed by  intersection of two prismatic ( non circular) cylinders.

Comment: @ Megannn: Images of  the parabolic, cubic cylinders are added in 3D. Intersection line in not shown thick. (can be done if time allows). The returning vertex/nose of the parabolic cylinder explains why the $y$ coordinate  terminates backward.

Answer (score 0):

From the surface $y = x^2$, you know the $y$ coordinate of any point on that surface, given only the $x$ coordinate of that point.
From the surface $z = \frac23 x^3$, you know the $z$ coordinate of any point on that surface, given only the $x$ coordinate of that point.

Now suppose the point $(x,y,z)$ is on the intersection of those two surfaces.
If we know $x$, then we know $y$ because that point must be on the first surface, and we know $z$ because that point must be on the second surface.
In fact, if we know $x$, then we can simply write the coordinates of the point as
$$(x,y,z) = \left(x, x^2, \frac23 x^3\right).$$
Now it should be clear that one and only one such point exists for each real number $x$, so the intersection of the two surfaces is a curve in three dimensions with $x$ coordinates that run monotonically from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Once you know the curve, you can forget about the surfaces.
We don't use them again.

Regarding concerns that were raised in comments,
you have been given the speed of the particle:
$$ \frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}=1630.$$
Supposing this was presented as a math problem rather than a physics problem, it is reasonable to assume that if specific units are not given, we're intended to use "math units" in which one (unnamed) unit of speed equals one unit of distance per unit of time. So I would not worry about the units.

What you *do* want to be concerned with is how to relate the speed $\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}$
to the three components of velocity, namely
$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$, $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}$,
and $\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}$.
To do this, you can use the equation
$$\left(\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
 = \left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2.$$
To simplify this, you can use what you know about the two surfaces the particle is riding on to determine $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ and $\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}$, which will enable you to rewrite $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}$ and $\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}$ in terms of $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$.

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}
 &= \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}
 = 2x \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, \\
\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}
 &= \frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}
 = 2x^2 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, \\
\end{align}

so
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
&= \left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
 + \left(2x \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
 + \left(2x^2 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 \\
&= (1 + 4x^2 + 4x^4) \left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 \\
&= (1 + 2x^2)^2 \left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2, \\
\end{align}

and therefore (since we are told in the problem statement that
$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$ is positive),

$$
\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}
 = \left\lvert (1 + 2x^2) \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \right\rvert
 = (1 + 2x^2) \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}.
$$

For $x = -9$, we find that $1 + 2x^2 = 163$, and therefore

$$ (1 + 2x^2) \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = 1630 $$

implies that $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = 10.$
It follows that

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}
&= 2(-9) \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = -180, \\
\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}
&= 2(-9)^2 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = 1620, \\
\end{align}

You can easily confirm that these three components of velocity give a total speed of $1630$.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]; tmin = -9; tmax = -8.5;
NDSolve[{X'[t]^2 + Y'[t]^2 + Z'[t]^2 == 1630.^2, 
   Y'[t] Sqrt[Y[t]] == Z'[t], Z'[t]/X'[t] == 2 X[t]^2, X[-9] == -9., 
   Y[-9] == 81., Z[-9] == -486.}, {X, Y, Z}, {t, tmin, tmax}];
```

[image]

EDIT1:

To solve numerically from parametrization
$(t,t^2,2 t^3/3)$ we have by Chain Rule of differentiation
$$ \frac{y^{3/2}}{z}= const.\to \frac{y'\sqrt{y}}{z'} =1$$
Similarly
$$\frac{z}{x^3}=const.\to \frac{z'}{x^2 x'} =2$$

EDIT2:
After sign change for sqrt (y) it works ok.

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you include $y = x^2$ and $z = \frac23 x^3$ in the set of equations to solve? It looks like you have plotted a completely different curve: $y$ should not be decreasing as $x$ decreases from $-9$.

Comment: I think I see why $Y$ is going in the wrong direction. You used `Sqrt[Y[t]]` as if it were $X$, but in this part of the curve $X$ is negative, so `Sqrt[Y[t]]` has the wrong sign.

Comment: Please see the edit. All three components $( x,y,z )$ decrease from BC.  Obtained derivatives by Chain Rule. All velocities check, so seems OK.

Comment: It's abundantly clear from the graphs that in the motion you have computed, $y \neq x^2$ at every $t > -9$. So right away we know this is not a solution to the problem in the question. Suppose you have the parameterization $(t,t^2,2t^3/3)$ as you say, then at $t=-9$, $y=81$, $y'=dy/dt=2t=-18$, $z'=dz/dt=2t^2=162$, and $y'\sqrt y/z'=-1$, not $1$. Besides, the problem statement says $x$ should be increasing.

Comment: What happens if you remove `Y'[t] Sqrt[Y[t]] == Z'[t], Z'[t]/X'[t] == 2 X[t]^2` and replace these equations with `Y[t] == X[t]^2, Z[t] == 2 X[t]^3/3`?

Comment: Then if would not take off at all! Error message is [ NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.]

Comment: @David K: However, with correction of $ \sqrt y$ to negative as you suggested , it seems to work now ok. When velocity checked before I was happy and did not look closely until you pointed out. However $x$ decreases and OP's this question part cannot be satisfied it looks.

Comment: Interesting! OK, I see from the documentation of NDSolve that it wants differential equations, not constraints, so I suppose you can't use $y=x^2$ directly. ... Without the constraint that $dx/dt>0$, there should be two solutions, one in each direction along the curve. NDSolve seems to have found one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Let the intersection line be parameterized on time $t$ as

$$ (x,y,z)=(t,t^2,\frac23 t^3)$$

Velocity vector
$$ (\dot x,\dot y,\dot z)=(1,2 t,2 t^2)$$

the speed

$$=\sqrt{1+4t^2+4t^4}= \pm(1+2t^2 
) $$

Evaluating  coordinates they check ok, as at  $ x=t=-9,$

$$ (x,y,z)=(-9,81, -486) $$

Evaluating speed we get at this instant $ \pm 163; $

Given speed is ten times this, can be rejected as being inconsistent.

Comment: The factor of ten just shows that your parameterization is inconsistent with the problem statement. But there's no need to parameterize on time at the very beginning; you could just parameterize on $x$. An explicit parameterization on time appears to be a bad idea here; I would look only at the speed at the point in question, not elsewhere on the curve.

Comment: Agreed, your point is well taken.

Comment: @ David K: I am uploading a Mathematica code that numerically solves for the three velocity components. There is no real solution $t \approx >-8.7;$ I am sure you can take the solution further analytically, for which I am requesting you.